# Unity: Everything freezes upon switching workspaces

Tags: 18.04, unity, workspaces, input-devices

I am using 19.10 on an HP Elitedesk with Intel i7.
I am currently using unity for the GUI client.

### The Problem

During the transition from different workspaces, the screen freezes all of a sudden. Although there is no apparent trigger. It just happens randomly.

## Some outputs of diagnostic commands

### The graphics card:

According to `About this Computer`, The computer uses graphics card with code name `NV106`. 
It's NVIDIA card. `NV160 GeForce RTX 2060, GeForce GTX 1660 Turing` according to https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/

### `free -h`

```
[someone@someone ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        1.6G         27G        135M        1.7G         29G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

### Output of `fsck -f`

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/nvme0n1p3: 625393/11386880 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 13969703/45515776 blocks
```

### Output of the relevant parts of `Disks` app

[image: Home drive]
[image: Data disk]

### Output of `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Output of `sysctl vm.swappiness`

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

### ** Result of memory test **

Tested the memory using tool provided at https://www.memtest86.com/ 
The result is the screenshot below.
[image: Memory test result]

## **Related Symptoms**

1. On boot, some times (randomly) screen gets blurry like seeing an old monitor through a digital camera.
2. Also, some times (randomly) keyboard and mouse doesn't work at the login window, so I can't type a password and log in.

I have no clue why this is happening, and I don't even have idea where to check for potential causes. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103385/discussion-on-question-by-tom-18-04-keyboard-mouse-etc-stops-working-at-some-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't have many clues as to the nature of your problem, we'll do an overall check.

**Let's check your file systems...**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p3`
  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Let's check your BIOS version...**

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

Then go to the https://support.hp.com web site, armed with your model #, and see if there's a newer BIOS available.

**Let's check your Samsung firmware...**

If you have Windows, boot into it, go to https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/, and download their "Samsung Magician", run it, and see if it finds new firmware.

**Let's test your memory...**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

So far, we've found a 2G /swapfile, and an unused 50G swap partition, and 20G of leftover Windows partitions, all on the boot 256G SSD.

**Update #2:**

Model # is "HP EliteDesk 800 G3 Base Model Small Form Factor PC"

See https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitedesk-800-g3-small-form-factor-pc/15257618/model/15257622

BIOS current version is 2.01, where the latest one is 2.31

**Update #3:**

See https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00007682 for instructions on how to update the BIOS (theoretically without using Windows). You might have to go to the local computer store and use one of their demo Windows machines to create the USB flash drive required.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDUCfU-e-A for how to update the BIOS from Linux... although this may, or may not, be possible with the .exe that comes from HP.

**Update #4:**

The final solution was to upgrade from the nouveau video driver, to the Nvidia driver v4.35 using the `Software & Updates` app, Additional Drivers tab.

Comment: Sorry the latest BIOS version was 2.31.

Comment: @Tom also remember... that you've got 70G of unused partition space on your HDD/SSD that can be reallocated to the Ubuntu partition. Do you know how to do that, or do you need my help with that? Then there's also the BIOS update...

Comment: I would move the Update4 to the beginning just to clarify what actually worked

Comment: @Tom thanks for the suggestion, however, moving it looses the time sequence.

Comment: but what people needs is the solution!

Comment: @Tom I appreciate your feedback. **I've been doing this for a while**, so I know that most/many users just immediately scroll down to the bottom of an accepted answer to see what finally fixed the problem :-)

Comment: Okay. I understand. All is good. Thank you very much!