# 18.04: Freezing gnome 3

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cpu, gpu

I have installed GNOME3 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with the 5.3.0-26-generic kernel, but when I log in the computer freezes a lot, so I must log in with gnome 3 xorg and that way I'm ok.

I have an NVIDIA Quadro p4000 and my CPU is a [i9-9900K](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186605/intel-core-i9-9900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html) (which has Intel HD Graphics 630). I didn't install any driver, because I prefer to know your answers first.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Hi. here's my lsb_release -a and uname-r to know the kernel

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

5.3.0-26-generic

Comment: c.f. this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203138/unity-everything-freezes-upon-switching-workspaces update Update #4

Comment: 1) As suggested below and in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204396/slow-ui-rendering-after-kernel-update please try the 5.0 kernel. 2) Tom above suggested changing to the NVIDIA driver v4.35 using the Software & Updates app, in the Additional Drivers tab.3) Ubuntu 18.04 already has GNOME3 installed by default. Did you reinstall GNOME3, or are you referring to the default Desktop Environment which comes with Ubuntu 18.04?